# Is it possible to do this regex operation with java in one line?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

**IS:**

```
String: "THE POWER WITH ME/STAR WARS I"
```

There is between 1 and 4 whitespaces randomly.

**SHOULD:**

```
String: "THEPOWERWITHME/STAR WARS I"
```

Delete all whitespaces before "/"

**REQUEREMENTS:**

Single line and to use:  `String.replaceAll("REGEX", "")` Method.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
"THE POWER WITH ME/STAR WARS I".replaceAll("(?=.*\\/)", "");
```

**Should**: `return "THEPOWERWITHME/STAR WARS I";`

---

I've tryed many regex configration and checked many topics in stackoverflow but couldnt make it, maybe someone can help me with that?

[image]

Comment: Do the spaces appear only at certain places, or anywhere in the string? i.e. will you ever get this as input: `THE PO WERWITHME/ST ARW ARSI`?

Comment: Yes its random, there is always between 1 to 4 whitespaces randomly.

Comment: Do not add the answer within the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of a positive look-ahead and capture all spaces before a `/` is encountered:

```
String.replaceAll( ' (?=.*/)', '' )
```

Comment: Your expression probably works but not for Java, its looks like JS?

Comment: @JurijsInfiniteCode You may wish to try again or post your attempt because this should work in Java.

Comment: `String str = "THE POWER WITH ME/STAR WARS I";
        str = str.replaceAll( " (?=.*/)", "" );
        System.out.println( str );`

Comment: @JurijsInfiniteCode Your screenshot is not using my example. If you wish to accuse my regex of not working then at least use the regex I provided...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus output of your regex: /T/H/E/ /P/O/W/E/R/ /W/I/T/H/ /M/E//STAR WARS I  - when I used replaceAll("(?=.*/)", "/")

Comment: @JurijsInfiniteCode Please edit your comment to make it legible by using backticks `\``

Comment: I found the problem and it was my fault, im sorry. I havent seen that "WHITESPACE" before (?=.*/) it works awsome, thank you very much!